# jspm install github library

Tags: npm, jspm

I'm tring to use https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar after forking

I can `jspm install -dev github:pcompassion/react-big-calendar` fine.

But it's lacking `lib` directory, I think jspm is not running "scripts" in package.json  (Is it supposed to do?)

```
   "scripts": {
     "clean": "rimraf lib",
     "clean:examples": "rimraf examples/static",
     "less": "lessc --autoprefix=\"ie >= 10, last 2 versions\" src/less/styles.less ./lib/css/react-big-calendar.css",
     "assets": "cpy src/less/* lib/less",
     "build": "npm run clean && babel src --out-dir lib && npm run assets && npm run less",
     "build:examples": "npm run clean:examples && webpack --config webpack/examples.config.es6.js",
     "build:visual-test": "webpack --config webpack/visual-test.es6.js",
     "examples": "npm run clean:examples && webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --config webpack/examples.config.es6.js",
     "lint": "eslint src --ext .jsx --ext .js",
     "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9002",
     "test": "npm run lint",
     "tdd": "karma start",
     "release": "release"
   },
```

So I should go to the folder and mannualy do `npm install` ?

Comment: From the looks of it, yes, and then `npm run build` too. jspm installs what is published on github. If `main` in `package.json` points to non-existent file, jspm will not build it from the sources.

Comment: Since it's my fork, I guess I could change package.json for jspm to better behave? although I don't have a clue how to do that. Besides `npm install` is taking fairly long. I guess jspm install npm:react-big-calendar would reuse already installed packages, but `npm install` in the directory is installing everything it needs in its own node_modules.